# (SwiftUI) Is it possible to change the background color of the focused element of a DatePicker?

Tags: swiftui, datepicker

[image: Left: How it is at the moment, Right: How I want it to be]

Left is how it is at the moment, Right is how I want it to be.

Here is the reproducible code:

```
 if reminderSet {   
   DatePicker("", selection: $deadline, displayedComponents: [.date, .hourAndMinute])
    .datePickerStyle(.wheel)
    .applyTextColor(.customBlack)
    .onChange(of: deadline) { value in
                        isEdited = true
  }
 }
```

Comment: I believe the right image is a custom DatePicker not a provided DatePicker by SwiftUI, so you can't achieve this with SwiftUI modifiers. You can try making a custom DatePicker.

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes it is a custom design. So it seems I need to create a custom picker just for the background color.